# Implementing Ti.goosh push notification module in Titanium for Firebase support

Tags: android, firebase, module, push-notification, titanium

I have implemented Ti.goosh module in my app for sending push notification from Firebase. I followed [this git document](https://github.com/caffeinalab/ti.goosh/%22this%22) and created a new project in Google Developer Console API. I got a Project Number from there and used it as "GCM sender ID" in tiapp.xml.  Then I added following code in my index.js controller.

```
var TiGoosh = require('ti.goosh');
TiGoosh.registerForPushNotifications({


    // The callback to invoke when a notification arrives.
    callback: function(e) {
    
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data || '');
    
    },

    // The callback invoked when you have the device token.
    success: function(e) {

        // Send the e.deviceToken variable to your PUSH server
        Ti.API.log('Notifications: device token is ' + e.deviceToken);

    },

    // The callback invoked on some errors.
    error: function(err) {
        Ti.API.error('Notifications: Retrieve device token failed', err);
    }
});
```

When I run app, success block execute and i got the device token. But I didn't get the message from firebase. I also couldn't understand where the server key and API key from firebase should be included in this module to link with my app.

How can I understand the whole thing? It seems that push notification in Titanium is very complex with very poor documentation.

Comment: look into the firebase module https://github.com/hansemannn/titanium-firebase

Comment: implemented but not working in my side. Couldn't get any notification in my app from firebase

Answer (score 0):

Use [this php script](http://Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(chooser);) to send notification and confirme you receive the data with ti.goosh

you need to include your api key and device token (registration_ids) in the script